# Invalid XML in a varbinary(max) column in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

So I got a `varbinary(max)` column in SQL Server 2005 and it's full of XML. A few records somewhere have truncated XML so they're invalid.

This means if I run a

```
SELECT CAST(myVarbinaryColumn as XML) ...
```

it blows chunks.

How can I filter out/skip invalid xml ?

When I've done similar with a varchar that supposedly has dates I could use `ISDATE(blah) = 1`. So an equivalent `ISVALIDXML()` would be nice.

Please don't comment about "Why isn't the column XML datatype anyway.." This happened in the past and I don't have a time machine.

Comment: Hmm interesting, the final bytes will always be the same so I could filter out those that don't match ? Luckily in this scenario the xml all use the same schema so they should all have a matching closing root element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to write a custom [CLR function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131043.aspx), perhaps using [XmlDocument.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load.aspx). In the CLR you could trap the error on a failed load and return an appropriate result.

**EDIT**: The code below would also work although it's not as elegant as a UDF. Unfortunately, we can't use TRY/CATCH in a UDF.

```
create procedure dbo.usp_IsValidXML(@XMLCandidate varbinary(max), @Return bit output)
as
begin
    declare @x xml
    begin try
        set @x = cast(@XMLCandidate as xml)
        set @Return = 1
    end try
    begin catch
        set @Return = 0
    end catch
end
go

declare @test1 varbinary(max)
declare @test2 varbinary(max)
set @test1 = cast('<data>asdf</data>' as varbinary(max))
set @test2 = cast('<data>asdf</da' as varbinary(max))

declare @IsValid bit
exec dbo.usp_IsValidXML @test1, @IsValid output
select @IsValid
exec dbo.usp_IsValidXML @test2, @IsValid output
select @IsValid

drop procedure dbo.usp_IsValidXML
```

Comment: Yes, and create a persistent calculated column based on it, so it's not called every time you go `where valid_xml = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I had that `IsValidXML()` function, too..... unfortunately, I don't think there's anything like that.....

Just a thought: is there anything you could check for to filter out the invalid XML??

E.g. could you filter out all those strings that don't end in `.....</data>` or something like that?? (seeing that you say your invalid XML is typically truncated XML, so I would think the closing tag - `</data>` or whatever - would be missing in those cases).